# WPF Designer throws error when string resources are used in code behind

Tags: c#-4.0, wpf-controls, resx

I have a wpf custom control (in AssemblyA) that references a string resource from an resx file in an external assembly (AssemblyB).

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            // ...
            // Do Stuff
            // ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ExceptionCodes.Ex50000, ex);
        }
    }
```

When I add the custom control (in AssemblyA) via a dll reference to a page in another project (AssemblyC) in another solution, the control fails to display in the designer. Instead, the designer displays a nice big red cross with the message 
    FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'AssemblyB'. 
The AssemblyB was also added as a dll reference to AssemblyC.

Removing the the references to the string resource in AssemblyA removes the error and allows the control to display correctly in the designer. Unfortunately, this is not an option as the string resources are used throughout the application for support reasons.

Creating an resx file in AssemblyA also removes the error but decentralises the resources which is not an option for on going development.

Based on the above, the designer is obviously not loading the resource assembly. Any insights would be appreciated.

To Summarise

CustomControl in Assembly A in Solution 1 references a string resourced from a resx file in Assembly B in Solution 1. Assembly C in Solution 2 has a dll reference to both Assembly A and Assembly B. A UserControl in Assembly C uses CustomControl in Assembly A. The Visual Studio WPF designer throws a FileNotFound exception when displaying the UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

Let it throw error, just check whether your are able to complie and run, the Make the assembly In Solution C as exe and try to run it. Because with Visual studio 10.0.4, i have see that exception many times, but if it is complied it doesn't give any compiler error, just try to compile and run it

Comment: Thank you for responding. I starting to think that no-one wold. I re-read my question and realised that I had not said the solution compiles and runs without a problem. The error is only in the designer. Since assemblies A and B (control and res assemblies) are part of a toolkit/framework for a number of development projects, having the designer fail is not an option.

Comment: We do have an interim solution that I will highlight here for other viewers but does not give me the solution I am looking for. **Put assembly B (the resource assembly) in the GAC.** This solves the designer problem but raises 'distribution complexities' that we are not willing to pursue at this time. I am still hopefull of finding a solution that will allow the inclusion of a dependencies folder in a solution.